# Printing Array without any loop or recursion

Tags: php, arrays

is there is a way to Print array without any loop or recursion in php?

Comment: Like `print_r`, `var_dump`, `var_export`, etc.?

Comment: The question is a bit vague. Is it for a reason, or just to see it's contents.

Comment: is there is a *reason* to print array without any loop or recursion in php?

Comment: You could copy-paste millions of "if (isset($array[0])) echo $array[0]; if (isset($array[1])) echo $array[1]; ..."

Comment: You should give a hint what you want to do and why to get better results/right answers for your question. Is this for debug or end user output? Need formating or do you want to write to a stream? Do you need access to its values or is only a callback required for every entry? Give us some hints for the field of usage.

Answer (score 8):

[`print_r()`](http://php.net/print_r) or [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/var_dump)

Answer (score 7):

You could try  [print_r($array);](http://au.php.net/print_r) or [var_dump($array);](http://au.php.net/var_dump) to display key/value information about the array. This is used mainly for debugging.

Alternatively if you want to display the array to users, you can use implode to stick the elements together with custom "glue", [implode(' ',$array);](http://au.php.net/implode).

Answer (score 3):

`print_r` is the function your looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want.

print_r() prints human-readable information about a variable but var_dump() displays structured information about expressions that includes its type and value.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your wanted result. You could use several functions for different purposes.

Here are some examples:

You can use [print_r](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) for debug output.

```
<?php
    $a = array ('a' => 'Apfel', 'b' => 'Banane', 'c' => array ('x', 'y', 'z'));
    print_r ($a);
?>
```

... will produce

```
Array
(
    [a] => Apfel
    [b] => Banane
    [c] => Array
        (
            [0] => x
            [1] => y
            [2] => z
        )
)
```

If you need some specific formated result/output you could use [array_walk](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
<?php
$fruits = array("d" => "Zitrone", "a" => "Orange", "b" => "Banane", "c" => "Apfel");

function test_alter(&$item1, $key, $prefix)
{
    $item1 = "$prefix: $item1";
}

function test_print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$key. $item2<br>\n";
}

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');

array_walk($fruits, 'test_alter', 'Frucht');

array_walk($fruits, 'test_print');
?>
```

... will produce

```
d. Zitrone
a. Orange
b. Banane
c. Apfel

d. Frucht: Zitrone
a. Frucht: Orange
b. Frucht: Banane
c. Frucht: Apfel
```

An even more generic way might be [iterator_apply](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.iterator-apply.php)

```
<?php
function print_caps(Iterator $iterator) {
    echo strtoupper($iterator->current()) . "\n";
    return TRUE;
}

$it = new ArrayIterator(array("Apples", "Bananas", "Cherries"));
iterator_apply($it, "print_caps", array($it));
?>
```

... will produce

```
APPLES
BANANAS
CHERRIES
```

But in the end... they are all loop through the array internally, of course.
There are many other functions (e.g. [array_map](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php)) that might be the right choice for your coding... have a look at the documentation of php and search for [array functions](http://de.php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php).

Answer (score -2):

```
function num($a,$b){

    if($b<0)
    {
        return false;

    }
    else
    {
        echo $a * $b;

        num($a,--$b);
    }
}

$a=1;
$b=5;
```

Comment: What has this answer to do with the question?